# Pandas check if cell is null in any of two dataframes and if it is, make both cells nulls

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with same shape:

```
>>> df1.shape
(400,1200)
>>> df2.shape
(400,1200)
```

I would like to compare cell-by-cell and if a value is missing in one of the dataframes make the equivalent value in the other dataframe NaN as well.

Here's a (pretty inefficient) piece of code that works:

```
for i in df.columns: # iterate over columns
    for j in range(len(df1): # iterate over rows
        if pd.isna(df1[i][j]) | pd.isna(df2[i][j]):
            df1[i][j] = np.NaN
            df2[i][j] = np.NaN
```

How would be a better way to do this? I'm very sure there is.

Comment: `isna` will work on an entire dataframe.  `df1[pd.isna(df2)] = np.NaN` should do the whole array in one blast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple problem to solve with pandas. You can use this code:

```py
df1[df2.isna()] = df2[df1.isna()] = np.nan
```

It first creates *mask* of `df2`, i.e., a copy of dataframe containing **only** `True` or `False` values. Each NaN in `df2` will have a `True` in the mask, and every other value will have a `False` in the mask.

With pandas, you can use such masks to do bulk operations. So you can pass that mask to the `[]` of `df1`, and then assign it a value, and where each value in the mask is `True`, the corresponding value in `df1` will be assigned the value.